# pip install numpy - fails to install although there are no errors

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-ec2

I'm using Linux AMI on Amazon EC2 and I would like to install `numpy` and `scipy`. In theory, it should be quite straightforward, but I'm runnign into problems.

Here are my steps:

```
> sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.4
> sudo virtualenv -p python3.4 my_env
> sudo chmod -R 777 my_env
> . my_env/bin/activate
> pip install numpy
```

Installing `numpy` returns:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
Successfully installed numpy
```

But it does not seems to work, because running `pip freeze` and `pip list` does not show any trace of `numpy`. The fact that I'm missing the package is obvious when I try to run `pip install scipy`:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz
Collecting numpy>=1.6.2 (from scipy)
  Using cached numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
 ImportError: No module named 'numpy'  Running setup.py install for scipy
    Complete output from command /usr/lib/python3.4/my_env/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wq1cn43p/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mjftl3bs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/lib/python3.4/my_env/include/site/python3.4/scipy:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-wq1cn43p/scipy/setup.py", line 253, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-wq1cn43p/scipy/setup.py", line 241, in setup_package
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have the lastest pip version, 7.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up your virtualenv to use python3 you also have to use `pip3`

```
virtualenv -p python3.4 env
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install numpy
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know about this connection. 
Actually I got the same error when I tried to use pip3. But knowing this, and knowing that I do not have to use 3.4, I opted for Python 2.7 and pip. Now everything installs as expected.

Comment: Still a bit strange, it should work with pip3. I can test it when I get home